# Syntax error in temporary build file

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, syntax

I'm building a fairly standard razor/c# page for an internal website.  Its basically a wrapper around a query that provides valid arguments for a db query.

The page is generating an error in Asp_Web_?????.cshtml when built.  For the life of me I cannot find the error.  Included below is the source of the page

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "ABC Floor Limits";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@Page.Title.</h1>
    <h2>Adjust.</h2>
</hgroup>


@{
    var DbCustom = Database.Open("Online_Ctrack6_Custom");
    var DbCustLogs = Database.Open("Online_CustLogs");

    int vehicleId = -1;
    string currentAction;

    if(IsPost)
    {
        vehicleId = Request.Form["vehicleId"].AsInt();
        string applianceName = Request.Form["applianceName"];
        int floorHours = Request.Form["hours"].AsInt();
        DateTime? dateToParse;
        DateTime dateTaken;
        string result = "";


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["dateTaken"]) == false)
        {
            var dtValue = new DateTime();
            if (DateTime.TryParse(Request.Form["dateTaken"], out dtValue))
            {
                dateToParse = dtValue;
            }
            else
            {
                dateToParse = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dateToParse = null;
        }

        currentAction = Request.Form["action"];
        if (currentAction == "updateHours")
        {
            try
            {
                dateTaken = (DateTime)dateToParse;
                result = doProcessHoursForm(DbCustLogs, vehicleId, applianceName, dateTaken, floorHours);
            }
            catch (InvalidDataException ex)
            {
                @:<div class="error">@ex.Message</div>
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                @:<div class="error">@ex.ParamName cannot be null.<br />@ex.Message @ex.ParamName</div>
            }
            finally
            {
                @:<div class="result">@result</div>
            }

        }
    }

    List<SelectListItem> listVehicles = null;
    try 
    {
        listVehicles = doCreateVehicleList(DbCustom, vehicleId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        @:<div class="error">@ex.Message<br />@ex.InnerException.Message</div>
    }

    string floorSql = "SELECT [NodeId],[PrimaryPropertyValue],[ID],[PumpADurationSec],[PumpAFloorSec],[PumpAFloorDate],[PumpATotalSec],[PumpBDurationSec],[PumpBFloorSec],[PumpBFloorDate],[PumpBTotalSec],[VacuumDurationSec],[VacuumFloorSec],[VacuumFloorDate],[VacuumTotalSec]   FROM [Ctrack6_Custom].[dbo].[vwVeoliaRunningTotals] ORDER BY [Id]";
    var floorGrid = new WebGrid(source: DbCustom.Query(floorSql), canPage: false, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "floorGrid");
}

<div class="section">
    <h3>Current Floor Values</h3>
    <p>This table lists the current floor values for ABC .  The values are saved internally as a number of seconds.</p>

@floorGrid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "VeoliaFloorTable",
    headerStyle: "columnHead",
    alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
    columns: floorGrid.Columns(
        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "NodeId", header: @Functions.Sorter("NodeId", "Node Id", floorGrid)),
        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "Id", header: @Functions.Sorter("Id", "Vehicle", floorGrid)),

        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "PumpAFloorSec", header: @Functions.Sorter("PumpAFloorSec", "Pump A Floor Sec", floorGrid), style: "alignRight"),
        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "PumpAFloorDate", header: @Functions.Sorter("PumpAFloorDate", "Pump A Floor Date", floorGrid), style: "nowrap"),

        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "PumpBFloorSec", header: @Functions.Sorter("PumpBFloorSec", "Pump B Floor Sec", floorGrid), style: "alignRight"),
        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "PumpBFloorDate", header: @Functions.Sorter("PumpBFloorDate", "Pump B Floor Date", floorGrid), style: "nowrap"),


        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "VacuumFloorSec", header: @Functions.Sorter("VacuumFloorSec", "Vacuum Floor Sec", floorGrid), style: "alignRight"),
        floorGrid.Column(columnName: "VacuumFloorDate", header: @Functions.Sorter("VacuumFloorDate", "Vacuum Floor Date", floorGrid), style: "nowrap")

    )
);

</div>

<div class="section">
    <h3>Update Floor Limits</h3>
    <p>This form allows you to update the floor limit specified for an appliance mounted on a vehicle.</p>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateHours" />
        <label for="selectVehicleControl">Choose Geozone:</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("vehicleId", listVehicles)

        <label for="selectApplianceControl">Choose Appliance:</label>
        <select name="applianceName" id="selectApplianceControl">
            <option value="-1">Choose an Appliance</option>
            <option value="Pump A">Pump A</option>
            <option value="Pump B">Pump B</option>
            <option value="Vacuum">Vacuum</option>
        </select>

        <label for="inputHoursText">Hour Reading:</label>
        <input name="hours" type="number" id="inputHoursText" min="0" max="9999999" size="7" required="required" />
        <span style="font-size:small">This will be converted into seconds</span>
        <br />

        <label for="dateTakenControl">Date Taken:</label>
        <input name="dateTaken" class="datetimefield" type="datetime" id="dateTakenControl" maxlength="19" required="required" />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Update Hour Reading" />
    </form>
</div>

@{

    public string doProcessHoursForm(Database DbCustLogs, int vehicleId, string applianceName, DateTime dateTaken, int floorHours)
    {
        int floorSeconds = floorHours * 3600;
        string sqlHoursUpdate = "exec sp_Veolia_update_floor_limit @0, @1, @2, @3";

        if(vehicleId != null && applianceName != null && dateTaken != null && floorSeconds != null)
        {
            var result = DbCustLogs.Execute(sqlHoursUpdate, vehicleId, applianceName, dateTaken.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), floorSeconds);
            if ( result != 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("Operation should only affect one record");
            }
            else 
            {
                return result + " row(s) changed";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string nullArg = "";
            if (vehicleId == null) { nullArg += "vehicleId,";}
            if (applianceName == null) { nullArg += "applianceName,"; }
            if (dateTaken == null) { nullArg += "dateTaken,"; }
            if (floorSeconds == null) { nullArg += "floorSeconds,"; }

            if (nullArg.Length > 1) { nullArg = nullArg.TrimEnd(','); }

            throw new ArgumentNullException(nullArg, "Argument cannot be null");
        }
        return "An error ocured";
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> doCreateVehicleList(Database db, int vehicleId)
    {
        var sqlVehicles = "SELECT NodeId, Id as VehicleName FROM vwVeoliaNodes ORDER BY Id";

        List<SelectListItem> listTemp = new List<SelectListItem>();
        listTemp.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Select a Vehicle",
            Value = "-1",
            Selected = false
        });

        try 
        {
            foreach (var item in db.Query(sqlVehicles))
            {
                if (item.NodeId == vehicleId)
                {
                    listTemp.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = item.VehicleName,
                        Value = item.NodeId.ToString(),
                        Selected = true
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    listTemp.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = item.VehicleName,
                        Value = item.NodeId.ToString(),
                        Selected = false
                    });

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception occurred building Vehicle List", ex);
        }
        return listTemp; 
    }
}
```

The error details follow:

**Error No:**   1
**Error Message:** } expected
**File:** c:\Users\Lukem\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\53d555f7\b262e6b6\App_Web_abcfloor.cshtml.cdcab7d2.abupdzvs.0.cs
**Line:** 760

The error in the tempfile is the EndContext reference:

```
BeginContext("~/VeoliaFloor.cshtml", 5970, 36, true);
WriteLiteral(" />\r\n        </form>\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n");
EndContext("~/VeoliaFloor.cshtml", 5970, 36, true);
```

I've installed a colour matching {} tool to help.  There seem to be no problems in the page, only when compiled to the temp file.  This is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are missing the `@functions` keyword in the section where you are declaring the methods.

Comment: And if im not using MVC, just using razor?

Comment: And how would you do that? Isn't your project an MVC one?

Comment: It's a "Web Pages" project, so no MVC, but does have Razor.  References in bin to:

- Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

Comment: Oh, you mean a Web Site project. It seems you are missing the `@functions` keyword in the section you are declaring the methods. After adding that I don't get that error anymore, but now the problem is in `@Functions.Sorter`. Where is that defined? BTW, you are comparing some `int` variables against `NULL`, and those are not nullable so you get a warning.

Comment: Functions.cshtml is defined under App_Code.  It just holds a method for sorting at this time

Comment: So did the `functions` keyword alone solve your problem?